# Using a form on DetailView, to submit data to a FormView - including data from context of the DetailView

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

A View(ViewA) is generating a template with context(contextA).

ViewA is inheriting from DetailView or ListView.

In ViewA I have a form(contact form), which on submit sends data to another View(ViewB) which inherits from FormView.

```
class ViewA(DetailView):
    model = Item

class ViewB(FormView):

    def get_success_url(self):

        send_contact__email(sender_email, receiver_email, title, item, message,location)
```

In the form I want to have visible fields but also multiple HiddenInput fields that send contextA data to ViewB, basically info about the page were the user accessed the contact form.

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):

    title = forms.CharField(max_lenght=255)
    message = forms.CharField()
    item = forms.HiddenInput()
    location = forms.HiddenInput()
    receiver_email = forms.EmailField()
    sender_mail = forms.EmailField()

<div class="modal">
     <form action="{{ item.contact_form_viewb }}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
             ....... # here to set fields 
             with value like {{ item.title}}
             ....... # here to set fields 
              <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
               <button type="button" Cancel</button>
      </form>
</div>
```

1. How do I integrate the form in ViewA considering is a DetailView and not a Create/Update View?
2. How do I set the  HiddenInput(s) in template to send data to ViewB?

Comment: Please include your template code, view code and from code in the question.

Comment: It might be simpler to store the attached data on the session object instead of using hidden fields to pass data between your views. Have you considered that approach? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/#examples

Comment: no, but I pass only in case the user contact (submit contact form -modal) not always

Comment: I think using a session would be simplest. If you want to use hidden fields, you must include the relevant `item` data in the render context. Override _get_context_data()_ to do so.